# Host ASP.NET Core Application on Raspbian with LocalDB

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, raspbian, localdb, raspberry-pi4

I am trying to host my Asp.Net Core application on a Raspberry Pi 4 with a LocalDB, but I get the following error message:

**An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
PlatformNotSupportedException: LocalDB is not supported on this platform.
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNI.LocalDB.GetLocalDBConnectionString(string localDbInstance)**

This is how my appsettings.json looks like:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "MyString": "data source=(localdb)\\MSSQLLocalDB;initial catalog=MyDatabase;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework"
  },
}
```

That's how I configure the Database in my Startup.cs:

```
   public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
   {
         services.AddDbContext<DatenbankKontext>(item => 
                    item.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("MyString")));
    }
```

It worked fine on Windows but I don't know how to properly configure it for Windows. How can I solve this?

Comment: Try configure connection string this way: "MyString": "Server=(localdb)\\mssqllocaldb....

Comment: I configured it as you wrote it but it didn't work at all

Comment: "With a SQL Server that works with LocalDB" - Huh? There is no such thing.

Comment: ok i solved the problem by using sqlite3